# How to logout user by id

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I am trying to logout an user (with all it current sessions) by another user, so for example an admin can force the logout of an user by a API call. Here's my current code:

```
function logoutUserGlobal(req,res) {
    var user = req.user,
        userid = req.params.id;

    if(user.role == "admin"){
        connection.query("DELETE FROM `sessions` WHERE `sessions`.`session` LIKE '%\"user\":" + userid  + "%'", function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(results);
            var response = {success: "test"}
            res.send(response).status(200).end();
        });
    }else{
        var response = {error: "not permitted"}
        res.send(response).status(200).end();
    } 
}
```

The sessions stored in the database are getting deleted but the user is somehow still logged in and if the user navigates on the page the session is being stored at the database again.

Thanks in advance and have a nice weekend!

Comment: You should be extremely careful when composing queries like that. Are you able to use placeholder values instead of string concatenation? [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) has really good support for this.

Comment: @tadman `mysql` has various [escaping options too](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#escaping-query-values).

Comment: @robertklep The `?` approach is the best way. Good link, thanks, if that's the one being used here.